# paging in a gridview based on a year field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I am trying to find a way to page through a gridview table by year. In my database I have a "season" field and I want all of the data from 2014 shown on one page, all the data from 2013 on another, etc. This would also require different numbers of rows based on the year.

Comment: Don't think you can do that.  Possibly look into master/detail.  One grid with a list of years and the other grid to display that year's data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

Comment: I thought there might not be a way to do it, but that might be helpful - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. I wouldn't use the default paging of the gridview to handle this. Instead, I would buttons (or linkbuttons) to imitate the paging so that you control the paging. This way, you will be able to handle the change in year as well as control what is displayed.

The Steps are as follows:

1) Add your gridview to the page with a big page size just to display everything

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvRequests" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="9999"> </asp:GridView>
```

2) Bind the Per Year data to it in the code behind since you are display everthing per year in your page load. As well as store a variable to track the year

```
public int CurrentYear
{
    get {
        if(ViewState["currentYear"] != null)
            return (int)ViewState["currentYear"];
        return 2014; //Default
    }
    set {
        _ViewState["currentYear"]= value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dgvRequests.DataSource = GetYearData(CurrentYear); //Or Your variable
        dgvRequests.DataBind();
        }
}
```

3) Make controls to control the page. I used Link Buttons

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrevious" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnPrevious_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnlNext" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnlNext_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

4) On the click event, control the paging of the gridviews via the click event

```
protected void lbtnlNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvRequests.DataSource = GetYearData(++CurrentYear); //Or Your variable
    dgvRequests.DataBind();
}
protected void lbtnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvRequests.DataSource = GetYearData(--CurrentYear); //Or Your variable
    dgvRequests.DataBind();
}
```

That should allow you to "Page" in essence by using controls instead of the paging feature.

** The GetYearData function is your function in which you grab your data from

** You may also want to display the current year of data your are displaying